# One service throw exception when I use Injector.get()

Tags: angular

I have a service for making http requests. Let's consider one method:

```
export class JsonApiService {
 constructor(private http: Http, private localStorageService: LocalStorageService) { }

      public get(url, params?, requestOptions: any = {}): Observable<any> {        
        const options = this.buildRequestOptions(requestOptions);
        const fullUrl = this.buildUrl(url);
        const urlWithQuery = this.addQueryParams(fullUrl, params);
        return this.http.get(urlWithQuery, options)         
          .map(this.extractData)
          .catch((e) => this.handleError(e));
      }
}
```

As yoy can see I use catch for caching errors. This is the `handleError` function:

```
private handleError(error: any): Observable<any> {
    let body  = error.json ? error.json() : '';
    if (!environment.production) {
      console.warn(error);
    }
    this.onError.next(body);       
    if(error.status === 0) {
      body.message = 'Can\'t connect to the server.';
    }

    return Observable.throw(body);
  }
```

Pretty standard code for this task. Now, I need to handle one specific server error response. The specific error json contains one field `checkIntegration`. So, I want to check error and if it contains this field. If yes then do some custom logic. I don't want to put this logic to `JsonApiService` itself, because I want to reuse this service from project to project and I actually do . I have been using it for the last 3 projects without any modification.

So, I wrote my custom error handler:

```
export class ErrorHandlerService extends ErrorHandler {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    super(true);

    let jsonApiService = this.injector.get(JsonApiService);
    jsonApiService.onError.subscribe((err) => {
      this.handleError(err);
    })
  }

  ...
}
```

As you can see I use `onError`. It's just `Subject`.
But, I have error on application startup: 
`Cannot read property 'notifyOptions' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'notifyOptions' of undefined
    at new LocalStorageService (local-storage.service.js:34)`

The error is thrown inside `local-storage.service`. It's not mine service, but I inject this service to `JsonApiService`. I believe not all services are created when I use injector in my handler. Any ideas?

PS. I use the following library for local storage:
https://github.com/phenomnomnominal/angular-2-local-storage/blob/master/src/local-storage.service.ts#L38

Answer (score 1):

In the code above `LocalStorageService` likely wasn't configured properly, because said property [originates in configuration provider](https://github.com/phenomnomnominal/angular-2-local-storage/blob/fb0cf088f843ce4202752ade1bc60b271e173045/src/local-storage.service.ts#L38).

The error is thrown on `JsonApiService` instantiation, it will prevent the provider from functioning normally. There's no point in handling the error with `onError` because the error is thrown long before `handleError`.

It should be caught in the place where problem provider is instantiated:

```
export class JsonApiService {
 private localStorageService?: LocalStorageService;
 constructor(private http: Http, private injector: Injector) { }
   try {
     this.localStorageService = injector.get(LocalStorageService);
   } catch (err) {
     ...
   }
```

But the proper solution is to address the cause of the problem in the first place.